# Azure Chatbot Demo run locally fail "InternalServerError: Unable to get resource information"

Tags: azure, chatbot, openai-api, internal-server-error

I am currently working on the Azure OpenAI+Cognitive Search Chatbot Demo. And as I try to run the demo locally, I kept getting this error message when using openAI API:

> Error: Unable to get resource information. {"error":{"code":"InternalServerError","message": "Unable to get resource information."}} 500 {'error': {'code': 'InternalServerError', 'message': 'Unable to get resource information.'}} {'Content-Length': '89', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'Not-Set', 'apim-request-id': 'edbe2b70-ae2d-44d5-b786-286e18f72e44', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Tue, 01 Aug 2023 08:00:55 GMT'}

I have checked .env and printed out all the parameters, and all of them are correct. And it can also run on Azure's app service. The problem only occurred when I tried to run locally.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Unable to get resource information. {"error":{"code":"InternalServerError","message": "Unable to get resource information."}} 500 {'error': {'code': 'InternalServerError', 'message': 'Unable to get resource information.'}}

The above **`Internalservererror`** occurs in open-ai due to region problems and may be incorrect in the API key and API endpoint.

I tried the same code locally to run Azure OpenAI+Cognitive Search Chatbot Demo.

**Code:**

```
import os
import requests
import json
import openai
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

# Set up OpenAI API
openai.api_key = "xxxxx"
openai.api_base = "https://xxxxx.openai.azure.com/"
openai.api_type = 'azure'
openai.api_version = '2023-05-15'

# Set up Azure Cognitive Search
search_service_name = "xxxx"
index_name = "xxxxx"
admin_key = "xxxxxxx"
credential = AzureKeyCredential(admin_key)
client = SearchClient(endpoint=f"https://{search_service_name}.search.windows.net/", index_name=index_name, credential=credential)

def search_index(query):
    search_results = client.search(search_text=query)
    return list(search_results)

def generate_response(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="deployment1", #text-davinci-002
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )
    return response.choices[0]['text'].replace('\n', '').replace(' .', '.').strip()


def handle_input(input_text):
    search_results = search_index(input_text)
    if len(search_results) > 0:
        return search_results[0]['content']
    else:
        prompt = f"Q: {input_text}\nA:"
        response = generate_response(prompt)
        return response


def run_chatbot():
    print("Welcome to the Azure OpenAI+Cognitive Search Chatbot Demo!")
    while True:
        # Get user input
        user_input = input("You: ")
        # Handle user input and generate response
        response = handle_input(user_input)
        # Print response
        print("Chatbot:", response)


run_chatbot()
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome to the Azure OpenAI+Cognitive Search Chatbot Demo!
You: dhoni
Chatbot: Dhoni is a former Indian cricketer and the current captain of the Indian national cricket team. He is considered one of the greatest cricket captains of all time.
```

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Azure OpenAI via API results in 500 internal Server error - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1327662/azure-openai-via-api-results-in-500-internal-serve)
- [Azure Open AI service Internal Error 500 - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1323507/azure-open-ai-service-internal-error-500) by AshokPeddakotla-MSFT.